# https with http requests works on ios mobile, not desktop?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ssl

I have a https website with mixed content at https://ambieye.com — it blocks insecure http requests on Chrome Desktop, Android Chrome, as expected.
Yet non-secure http requests are **not blocked** on iOS mobile safari and on iOS Chrome.

Thus a question: does iOS not block mixed-content (http requests) on https pages? 
Are the lack of security blocks documented somewhere on apple.com, will it change in the near future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not block passive content such as image but blocks active content such as js, css.
Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#Mixed_passivedisplay_content
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content